# Our code styling looks different on simulator vs deployed on app through testflight. Need help debugging

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

So i developed my application in react native+Expo, ejected the app, and tested the application on the IOS simulator. It works and looks great on the simulator. Then, when I deploy it to my actual phone on testflight everything looks smaller and off. I'm testing on the same device on simulator.

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how to remedy this problem, or even recreate it on the simulator. I tried doing a release build after seeing someone else suggest it, didn't help.

Any and all advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the real device you are using the same as the simulator? If not, then perhaps your app has a problem with responsive layout. There are several things you must do extra in order to make the app look similar on all of the devices. I have faced the same issue when my app was tested on iPhone6 simulator and I first saw it on real iPhone X.

Comment: it is the same device. What would you recommend doing?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot and example of style you are providing to a component that looks different? That would help, thanks. You can add it in edit to original post.